# Pandas 0.14.1 import dll error

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using python 2.6.6 (32bits) on windows 7 and I try to upgrade from Pandas 0.13.0 to Pandas 0.14.1
I can't upgrade to newer version of python due to IT policy.

I tried using the tar.gz package, using the compiled pandas version found here [pandas‑0.14.1.win32‑py2.6.exe](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pandas), even reinstalling everything (numpy, py-tz, dateutil...), but I got always the same error:

```
File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import hashtable, tslib, lib
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I defined the python path `PYTHONPATH` to `C:\Python26\Lib;C:\Python26\DLLs;C:\Python26\Lib\lib-tk;` but it does not make any difference. However the `hashtable.pyd`, `tslib.pyd` and `lib.pyd` do exist in the proper directory.

I've googled the problem, and in some case using the exe from the site of [Christoph Gohlke](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) helps , but I already tried and the error is always the same.

Any idea? So far I'm blocked to version 0.13.0 as even 0.13.1 gives the same error.

Thanks.

Comment: see here: http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/install.html#installing-pandas, easiest on windows to simply use conda and create your own environment (any version of python/numpy/pandas), already compiled.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I tried using conda, but it fails to create a new env with python 2.6: `ImportError: Module use of python26.dll conflicts with this version of Python` and I can't install python 2.7. Is there another way around?

Comment: you can certianly install python WITH conda, do that first (you can do it for 2.6 as well). pls read all the instructions.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work and because of IT requirement anaconda cannot access to internet.

Comment: you shouldn't try to compile on windows, its non-trivial. Is their a problem use Chris Gohlke's binaries?

Comment: Hi, thanks for you both for your help. Unfortunately, I installed Chris binaries (and make sure there is `libmnd.dll`) but I always got the message listed in my initial post. This either if I install a 32 bits or 64 bit of python/numpy/pandas. pands only works for me with the version 0.13.0 (previously downloaded from Chris site).